# CORS error with Elastic beanstalk JS SDK describeEnvironmentResources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

With an example right from [their docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticBeanstalk.html#describeConfigurationSettings-property):

```
var params = {
  EnvironmentIds: [ 'my_env' ],
};

elasticbeanstalk.describeEnvironments(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

The call makes a CORS POST request to `https://elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/`, which is denied.

How does one configure CORS for the elastic beanstalk JS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Set the allowed origin list for the connecting client. See the docs for more options. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-cors-corsrule.html

I would advise against using * and instead implement a whitelist in accordance with the OWASP recommendations shown here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CORS_OriginHeaderScrutiny

Comment: I'm looking in to it, but initially this makes no sense.  How would a CORS rule for one of my S3 buckets effect the OPTIONS returned by `https://elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/`?

Comment: The CORS whitelist must contain your referring system. I assumed you had control of both.